# Error on opening camera and getParameters

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-camera

This is the code from my MainActivity:

```
package com.simple.flashlight;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_menue);

        Button turnOnButtOn = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
        Button turnOnButtOff = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button2);
        Camera mCam = Camera.open(); //here is an error
        Parameters p = mCam.getParameters(); //here is an error

        turnOnButtOn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View cameraButton){
                //Turn ON
            }
        });

        turnOnButtOff.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View cameraButton){
                //Turn OFF
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and this what I have in the manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.simple.flashlight"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <permission
        android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am getting errors on `Camera mCam = Camera.open();` and `Parameters p = mCam.getParameters();` the errors are:
1. the method open() is undefined for type Camera.
2. the method getParameters() is undefined for type Camera.

I'm new to Android development, so maybe I have missed something really stupid, 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What errors? show logcat please.

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
The method open() is undefined for the type Camera Main.java /FlashLight/src/com/simple/flashlight line 20 Java Problem
The method getParameters() is undefined for the type Camera Main.java /FlashLight/src/com/simple/flashlight line 21 Java Problem

Comment: The log cat is empty, maybe because it is a compiler error and not a run time error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the `import android.graphics.Camera;`
It's confusing your calls and does not have an open() method.

Answer (score 0):

Delete import android.graphics.Camera; and when importing, import 'Camera'(android.hardware) instead of 'Camera'(android.graphics).